# Aspiration, palatalization, recording artefact or what?

Tags: prononciation, musique

Voici une belle interprétation de « [l'Hymne à la nuit](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hymne_%C3%A0_la_nuit) », musique de Rameau : [La nuit de Rameau (1958)](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=WCAmRV1snYc)

À 1:35 et à 1:55, le jeune soliste prononce ces paroles :

> aussi belle que le rêve ... plus douce que l'espérance

À mes oreilles, ces deux « que » sont prononcés d'une façon singulière. Je ne suis pas certain de ce que je perçois ni, vu que l'enregistrement a été fait il y a plus d'un demi-siècle, s'il y a même quelque chose à noter. S'agit-il de :

1. La [palatalisation](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Palatalisation), semblable à ce à quoi on s'attend dans certains accents, pour ne rien dire des autres langues romanes ?
2. L'[aspiration](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aspiration_(phon%C3%A9tique)) intensive, qui serait inattendue d'un francophone ?
3. Quelque chose d'autre ?
4. Le fruit de mon imagination ?

Merci !

Comment: je dirais probablement réponse 2, définitivement pas réponse 4. Quant à savoir pourquoi ? ...

Comment: @EmmanuelBRUNO Je penche pour cette réponse aussi après avoir réécouté la chanson ; il semble aspirer plusieurs consonnes, dont /t/ à 0:51 par exemple. Mais c'est irrégulier ...

Comment: J'entends seulement quelque chose avec le _que_ précédant l'_espérance_. Je n'ai malheureusement aucune connaissance en musique et je ne puis lire une partition, mais j'en ai vu une où il y a un long trait au pied de la lettre après ce _que_ là, mais pas après celui précédant rêve, où je vois plutôt ce même genre de trait suivant _belle_. Je n'ai pas les connaissances pour associer ce trait à l'un (ou plusieurs) des concepts que vous présentez. Merci !

Comment: À mes oreilles, il semble que le /k/ dans "que le rêve" est aspiré. A relevant paper (en anglais) about some general tendencies for stop aspiration in modern French: http://ling.snu.ac.kr/jun/under_phono/sample_paper.pdf

Comment: There may also be some relevant info here (I haven't looked though all of it yet): http://repository.ubn.ru.nl/bitstream/handle/2066/119022/119022.pdf?sequence=1

Comment: Je suis d'accord, il y a là définitivement quelque chose d'incongru à mes oreilles. Je me demande si (théorie très vague!) cela pourrait être lié à prononciation italianisante du Latin ecclésiastique, qui j'imagine devait être très présente dans les chants religieux de l'époque?

Answer (score 2):

Je dirais que c'est une aspiration du /k/ qui me rappelle l'[accent parisien](https://youtu.be/KT_XlcgAADo?t=13s). Dans la même vidéo, à 0:11 on entend d'ailleurs le chef de chœur faire un peu la même chose au /k/ de "recueilli". En tout cas pas facile à dire sur un vieil enregistrement avec une diction manifestement forcée pour le chant.